# Send Payment Link by Email via WorldPay API

Tags: worldpay

I have a customer who uses WorldPay to manually send out Emails with payment links for their customers to make payment. They would like to automate the sending out of emails with payment links. Therefore I need to somehow send WorldPay emails with payment links inside them via their API. Or get a unique payment link from the WorldPay API and send it to the customer in my own email.

The customer logs in via https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html which is an old WorldPay portal. I think it is called the Business Manager.

Is that possible, and has anyone done this before?

I am asking here because I am getting nowhere with the WorldPay help resources.

Comment: https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/wpg/hostedintegration/quickstart - see "Example XML Order". The response includes a payment link.

Comment: Thank you @Jaybird but it seems it is not possible at the moment. WorldPay said that the product that allows for that they are no longer offering because they are working on a new one which will be available some time next year. So at the moment, you literally cannot do it, unless you are already on a product which used to allow it.